# ISBLANK not working as expected

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I am using:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(B9),ISBLANK(C9)), "", C9-B9)
```

To stop my data from returning a zero.

However the data that I need to return is the difference between two months `=MONTH(L9)-MONTH(O9)`, which does not work in this formula.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? What are you expecting? What are you getting?

Comment: I am trying to return a blank field if their is no data in L9 or O9, which is working, however when there is data in these fields it is returning invalid data.  Example L9 = 2/15/16 and O9 = 8/15/16 and the result is -182.  I would like the returned data to be in months which would = 6

Comment: where does B9 and C9 come into this picture then?

Comment: that was just an example of the function I was using...this is the actual =IF(OR(ISBLANK(L9),ISBLANK(O9)), " ", L9-O9)

Comment: =IF(OR(ISBLANK(L9),ISBLANK(O9)), " ", (MONTH(O9)-MONTH(L9))) works for me.... except this will ONLY work where the dates are in the same year and don't cross the new year.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have two problems.

#### Date cell references

If you subtract L9 from O9, you will get 182 because there are 182 days between those dates, and Excel stores dates as the number of days since a reference date.  So, I suspect your formula with the ISBLANKs is doing the subtraction on L9 and O9 instead of B9 and C9.  If B9 contains =MONTH(L9) and C9 contains =MONTH(O9), subtracting B9 from C9 will yield 6.

#### ISBLANK cell references

I did a quick test in LO Calc, and it's possible that it treats blank cells differently than Excel.  I recreated your formula and deleted one of the dates, expecting a missing date to produce an error in the MONTH function.  However, it treated the blank cell as zero.  The MONTH of date `0` (the reference date, January 0, 1900, which equals December 31, 1899), is 12.  So the cell with the MONTH function will not be blank if a date cell is blank (it will always be either a number or an error).  You need the ISBLANK tests to reference the date cells (L9 and O9).